Creating input set for prediction for LSTM and target shifting
I am having difficulty figuring out if target shifting (shift(-1)) is important for time series prediction. I am trying to forecast the forex market one step ahead and ChatGPT says that LSTM do not require explicit target shift. Below is the example generated by the ChatGPT to show how its done.
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import LSTM, Dense

# Prepare input data for LSTM
sequence_length = 10

X = df[['Value']].values.reshape((1, sequence_length, 1))  # 1 sample, 10 time steps, 1 
feature

# The target (11th hour value) - we would generally have this as part of training data
y = np.array([30])  # Example target value for the 11th hour

# Define LSTM model
model = Sequential([
LSTM(50, activation='relu', input_shape=(sequence_length, 1)),
Dense(1)
])

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')

# Train the model (usually with more data, but for demo purposes, we'll use our single 
sample)
model.fit(X, y, epochs=200, verbose=0)

predicted_value = model.predict(X)

Is this example correct? Would this really try to predict the 11th value in a series of 1-10?
